How to set nano to show line numbers before text by default
How do I set nano to show line numbers before text by default?
Its annoying to have to nano -l <file> everytime.

Just found the solution.
Fist open nano's start up file
nano ~/.nanorc

Then enter
set linenumbers

You can actually set any option in this file.
All the info is in the nano documention
Nano Documentation

I think nano ~/.nanorc needs to restart the device this worked with the same file when reopened, but it doesn't work with the other files. I tried sudo nano /etc/nanorc this worked with any file directly.

Long time sysadmin here. Changing the behavior of any tool used by root always has unexpected side effects  - don't do it! Rather, read man sudoedit, and set up your EDITOR  and VISUAL environment variables.

sudo nano /etc/nanorc

after the file is opened, find these lines:
## Display line numbers to the left (and any anchors in the margin).
#set linenumbers

remove # in the #set linenumbers line, and save the file.
